# How to disallow Windows Update search for Language Packs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

Is there a way to force Windows Update to DO NOT search language packs for windows 7 (x64 for precision) ?

I what users cannot see MUIs, so I don't want to manually hide MUIs in all pcs, I'd like to set a registry entry or a policy to disallow WU *searching* and/or *listing* at all of these updates.

Something like a registry entry, to integrate into slipstreamed DVD ?

Comment: select all offered MUIs and hide them.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I'd like that user CANNOT see MUIs offered at all. Is there any registry and/or policy to set to ask WU to completely ingore them?

Comment: there is no setting that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no fine-grained control mechanism on the client side.
You can only do that if you run your own WSUS server and set the policy to the clients to update through that WSUS server.
On your own WSUS you have full control over what to publish to the clients.
E.g. on my WSUS I only supply English updates, no MUI's and I also keep a couple of other updates back (like the Windows 10 force upgrade stuff for Win7 and Win8 computers and the EU mandated browser-choice update).